# График из звукового файла.

Tags: график, mp3

Подскажите как построить график по данным **wav** файла, или **mp3**. Какая структура хранения данных в звуковых файлах.

Answer (score 3):

Например [здесь](http://audiocoding.ru/статьи/структура-wav-файла.html) найдете его заголовок, хранящий все необходимые вам данные.

Не сжатый **wav** (где `audioFormat` = 1) файл имеет очень простую структуру. В данные помещаются отсчеты с частотой `sampleRate` для `numChannels` каналов. Все, что вам нужно это считывать `bitsPerSample` бит, которые будут олицетворять собой значение сигнала (амплитуду) в конкретный момент времени. Вот и выводите их на график.

Единственное, продумайте масштабирование, ибо при частоте дискретизации в 8000Гц и моно канале, за одну секунду только вам придется вывести все 8000 отсчетов, представьте что будет если выводить 44 000Гц.